# Backbone : passing underscores templates in variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have problem with Backbones templates using Underscore.js.
I have all my templates in separate variables and when im passing them into my model im gettin "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'html' of undefined"

Here's my code ,

```
var YetiBoxView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',

    template_online : yetibox_status_online,
    template_offline : yetibox_status_offline,
    template_inactive : yetibox_status_inactive,


    initialize: function(){
        this.render();
    },

    render: function(){
        if( this.model.toJSON().status == "ONLINE") {
            this.$el.html(this.template_online(this.model.toJSON()));
        } else if (this.model.toJSON().status == "OFFLINE"){
            this.$el.html(this.template_offline(this.model.toJSON()));
        } else if(this.model.toJSON().status == "INACTIVE"){
            console.log(this.model.toJSON());
            this.$el.html(this.template_inactive(this.model.toJSON()));
    }}
});


var YetiBoxCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el : '#status_list',

    render: function(){
        this.collection.each(function(yetibox){
            var yetibox_view = new YetiBoxView({model: yetibox});
            this.$el.append(yetibox_view.el);
        }, this);
    }
});
```

Comment: Your code hasn't even gotten to your template variables yet - it's reading `this.$el` as undefined. This should never happen - `el` and `$el` should default to empty divs if not initialized. It may be that you are explicitly setting `el` in some incorrect way somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Thanks for anserw, i cant figure out whats the problem , still getting the same error

Comment: Try `console.log`ing `this.el` in the initialize, see if you get the expected `<li>` dom element. If you do, try again right in the render function. Everything here looks ok, I wouldn't be surprised if the error comes from code somewhere else in your project.

Comment: Hard to tell if the error is from `YetiBoxCollectionView` or `YetiBoxView` so also make sure that `#status_list` exists in the DOM when you create the collection view.